# Prove that $\cup_{\alpha \in J}\ \mathcal{T}_\alpha$ is a subbasis.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I was solving a problem in general topology. I found that this problem is based on this sub problem.

Let $\{\mathcal{T}_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be a  collection of topologies on $X$. I want to prove that $\cup_{\alpha \in J}\ \mathcal{T}_\alpha$ is a subbasis.

I noted that $X \in \mathcal{T}_\alpha$, but I could not prove $X = \cup_{U_\beta \in \cup \mathcal{T}_\alpha} U_\beta$.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need $J$ to be non-empty, so pick any $\beta \in J$. Then $X \in \mathcal{T}_\beta$ because it is a topology. So a fortiori $X \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in J} \mathcal{T}_\alpha$. It follows immediately that the union of that family is $X$ too. You're getting confused by an overdose of unions. You have a collection of subsets of $X$ one of which is $X$ itself already. Of course their union is going to be $X$.

Comment: IMHO, **every** collection of subsets of $X$ is a subbasis for some topology. That is how I was taught it. The generated base is just $\{X\}$ (the nullary intersection by convention) and all finite intersections of subbasic sets. Everything then works fine. Ceterum censeo etc.